# Documentation says `exports.activate`, but my extensions work without

Tags: javascript, vscode-extensions

The documentation ([page 1](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/activation-events)) says extensions need to `export function activate`.

> > **Note:** An extension **must** export an `activate()` function from its main module and it will be invoked **only once** by VS Code when any of the specified activation events is emitted. Also, an extension **should** export a `deactivate()` function from its main module to perform cleanup tasks on VS Code shutdown. Extension **must** return a Promise from `deactivate()` if the cleanup process is asynchronous. An extension may return **undefined** from `deactivate()` if the cleanup runs synchronously.

The web extension documentation ([page 2](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/web-extensions)) says web extensions should use `exports.activate`.

> - As with regular extensions, the extension's `activate/deactivate` functions need to be exported via the pattern `exports.activate = ...`.

*However, I have written 4 web extensions which work as expected **without** exporting an activate function.* (You can see them [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/publishers/AdamRaichu), source code links found on each extension's page).

**Why do my extensions work without exporting `activate`? Is the documentation wrong? Is there something I am losing by not exporting activate?**

---

My code is bundled by webpack from index.js (below) into dist/main.js.

```json
// package.json
{
...
  "main": "./dist/main.js",
  "browser": "./dist/main.js",
  "activationEvents": [
    "onCommand:zipViewer.extract",
    "onCommand:zipViewer.zip",
    "onCommand:zipViewer.openFileWithEditor",
    "onCustomEditor:zipViewer.ZipEdit"
  ],
...
}
```

```
// index.js
import cmds from "./cmds.js";
import ZipEdit from "./editor.js";

cmds.register();
ZipEdit.register();
```

```
// editor.js

// imports
// ...
export default class ZipEdit {
  static register() {
    return vscode.window.registerCustomEditorProvider(ZipEdit.viewType, new ZipEdit());
  }

  static viewType = "zipViewer.ZipEdit";
// ...
```

```
// cmds.js

export default class cmds {
  static register() {
    vscode.commands.registerCommand("zipViewer.extract", function () {
    // Registers all commands in this way...
```

---

### Update 12/31/2022

I created a branch [`test`](https://github.com/AdamRaichu/vscode-minecraft-lang/tree/_eager-activation-event-demo-archive) *(renamed 1/31/23)* in which I added a console.log message to extension.js, and added the `*` activation event to my package. I then ran the command `Developer: Install extension from loaction...` and pasted in [this url](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AdamRaichu/vscode-minecraft-lang/test/). Immediately I saw the extension was activated, and opened the console. The debug message was indeed present, which means an extension can listen to `*` without exporting `activate`. (I also tested by reloading a few times with the same result: debug message was present.) Also tested with `*` as only activation event.

Comment: How do you know when to initialize your extensions, without an activation function? When do you register your providers etc.?

Comment: Methods like `registerCommand` are called in the file designated as the entrypoint by package.json.

Answer (score 1):

> An extension must export an activate() function from its main module

Only applies to the [Start Up](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/activation-events#Start-up) activation event, which is only triggered when...

> will be activated whenever VS Code starts up.

The context you're missing is that the quote is listed under the [Start Up](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/activation-events#Start-up) header and not the [Activation Events](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/activation-events) header.

Meaning your extension does not *have* to export an activate function unless you use the `*` activation event, which listens to:

> multiple activation events

Comment: Thank you! This is truly the piece I was missing.

Comment: @AdamRaichu To test this, change your activationEvent to `*` , does your extension still work without an `exports.activate` ?

Comment: See edit to question. It did :/

Comment: @AdamRaichu  Did you try with `*` as the ONLY activationEvent?

Comment: No, I will try that now.

Comment: Debug message still present when `*` is the only activation event. (Commit 9b557a5)